run time error while running tests in rails
versions:
> ruby -v
ruby 3.3.6 (2024-11-05 revision 75015d4c1f) [arm64-darwin24]
> rails -v
Rails 8.0.0.1


user.rb model:
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2]

  enum :status, { active: 'active', blocked: 'blocked' }
  belongs_to :role, optional: true
  has_many :role_permissions, through: :role
  has_many :permissions, through: :role_permissions

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }
  validates :encrypted_password, presence: true
  validates :full_name, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_nil: true
  validates :uid, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_nil: true
  validates :provider, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_nil: true
  validates :avatar_url, length: { maximum: 255 }, allow_nil: true
  validates :status, inclusion: { in: statuses.keys }

  def has_permission?(action, resource)
    return true if permissions.exists?(name: '*:*')
    permissions.exists?(name: "#{action}:#{resource}")
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize

    if user.new_record?
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0, 20]
      user.full_name = auth.info.name
      user.avatar_url = auth.info.image

      user.role = Role.find_by(name: 'default') || nil
    elsif user.email != auth.info.email
      Rails.logger.warn "Email conflict: Google email #{auth.info.email} does not match existing user email #{user.email}."
    end

    user.save!

    user
  end
end

users_controller.rb:
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, except: [:index]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def edit
  end

  def sh  ow
    @user
  end

  def update
    if params[:user][:status].present?
      @user.status = params[:user][:status]
    end

    if params[:user][:role_id].present?
      role = Role.find_by(id: params[:user][:role_id])
      if role
        @user.role = role
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Invalid role selected."
        render :edit and return
      end
    end

    if @user.save
      redirect_to users_path, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "User was successfully deleted."
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:full_name, :email, :status, :avatar_url, :role_id)
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    unless @user
      flash[:alert] = "User not found."
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end

  def check_user_permission
    action = params[:action]
    resource = controller_name
    puts "find me here"
    puts action
    puts resource

    unless current_user.has_permission?(action, resource)
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "You don't have permission to perform this action on #{resource}."
    end
  end
end

spec/controllers/users_controller.rb:
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
  let(:admin) { create(:user, :admin) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }



  describe 'GET #index' do
    it 'returns a successful response' do
      sign_in admin
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_successful
      expect(assigns(:users)).to eq([admin, user])
    end
  end


end

spec/factories/permissions.rb:
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :permission do
    name { "" }
    trait :admin do
      name { "*:*"}
    end
  end
end


spec/factories/roles.rb:
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :role do
    name { "default" }
    permissions { [create(:permission)]}
    trait :admin do
      name { "admin" }
      permissions { [create(:permission, :admin)] }
    end

  end
end

spec/factories/users.rb:
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    encrypted_password { Faker::Internet.password }
    full_name { Faker::Name.name }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
    role { create(:role) }
    status { "active" }
    provider { 'google' }
    uid { Faker::Internet.uuid }
    avatar_url { Faker::Avatar.image }
    trait :active do
      status { "active" }
    end

    trait :blocked do
      status { "blocked" }
    end

    trait :admin do
      role { create(:role, :admin) }
    end
  end
end

I am getting error when i run the tests
/bin/zsh -c "bash -c 'env RBENV_VERSION=3.3.6 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/rbenv/1.3.0/libexec/rbenv exec ruby -x /Users/owner/github/work/pms/bin/bundle exec ruby /Users/owner/.rbenv/versions/3.3.6/bin/rspec /Users/owner/github/work/pms/spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --example UsersController'"
Testing started at 12:46 PM ...
Run options: include {:full_description=>/UsersController/}

Deprecation Warnings:

Rails 7.1 has deprecated the singular fixture_path in favour of an array.You should migrate to plural:


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

RuntimeError: Could not find a valid mapping for #<User id: 1, email: [FILTERED], full_name: "Steve Weber", uid: "c799b178-a201-483c-9546-32ef58866e2b", provider: "google", avatar_url: "https://robohash.org/laborenemout.png?size=300x300...", created_at: "2024-12-15 07:16:37.643769000 +0000", updated_at: "2024-12-15 07:16:37.643769000 +0000", status: "active", role_id: 1>

  0) UsersController GET #index returns a successful response
     Failure/Error: sign_in admin

     RuntimeError:
       Could not find a valid mapping for #<User id: 1, email: [FILTERED], full_name: "Steve Weber", uid: "c799b178-a201-483c-9546-32ef58866e2b", provider: "google", avatar_url: "https://robohash.org/laborenemout.png?size=300x300...", created_at: "2024-12-15 07:16:37.643769000 +0000", updated_at: "2024-12-15 07:16:37.643769000 +0000", status: "active", role_id: 1>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

1 deprecation warning total
1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed
Finished in 0.153122 seconds

Process finished with exit code 1


spec/rails_helper.rb:
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'devise'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  abort e.to_s.strip
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end


Does anyone know why is this happening ?
I think the problem is with devise or other thing, I want to know the reason this is happening

Do not use controller specs. Instead write a request spec:
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'User Administration', type: :request do
  let(:admin) { create(:user, :admin) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) } # use let! if you don't want this to be lazy loading

  context "when signed in as an admin" do
    before do
      login_as admin 
    end

    describe "GET /users" do
      let!(:users) { create_list(:user, 3) }
      it 'returns a successful response' do
        get users_path
        expect(response).to be_successful
      end
    end
  end

  context "when not authorized" do
    # @todo write specs that ensure that an authorized user is denied access
  end
end

This will create a spec that actually goes through the middleware stack (including Devise) and is not as bug prone. The use of controller specs is discouraged and they are solely retained for legacy compatibility.
As for the actual error it's because the mocks that Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers uses to stub out the whole damn authentication layer isn't working properly. But don't waste your life on this.
Beyond that the assigns method was depreachiated way back in 2015 so your spec won't work anyways unless you install the rails-controller-testing gem (don't). Even if you do the expectation expect(assigns(:users)).to eq([admin, user]) will fail.

let(:user) { create(:user) } is lazy loading. So the record is not created until you reference it. Use let! if you don't want that.
expect tests object equity and the User instances in your spec are not the same as the ones that the controller instanciates from the database. Test the ids instead of object equity.

Testing the interface directly between the controller and view in this way is simply something that's no longer done. Instead you do it indirectly by testing the rendered response.
If you're doing this because you're following a book/tutorial you might want to try to find a better source that reflects modern best practices.
